# tie two inout together vhdl

Tags: input, vhdl, output, bidirectional

I want to drive a birectionnal logic signal through the FPGA.
PGD_ICD <--> PGD_TARGET
for those who have recognized the Microchip ICD3 you know that PGD line is bidirectional.
I've read that we can't do something like that but have you any idea ?
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a bidirectional bus through an FPGA without knowing the bus protocol won't work.

While FPGA I/O pins do support tristate logic signals (floating output state), you will need to know when to drive a value onto the output, and when to tristate the output (high impedence, or 'Z').

Once you have a signal (for example `out_enable`) that is '1' when you want to drive a value and '0' when the output should be floating, you can use a tri-state buffer to drive the output:

```
out_pin <= out_signal when(out_enable='1') else 'Z';
```

Comment: many thanks, so i need to know the protool, yes its logical :)